# Java: Scanner input in an infinite loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I'm currently trying to make a simple program to test that certain characters in a string are where they are suppose to be. For instance the '/' inside a normal mm/dd/yy format. But for some reason I can't even get pass the scanner input because it just keeps asking for input. I've searched around and could find anyone with the exact problem I had, considering this is happening with just a stand alone scanner. I'm very new to Java so I assume this is a simple mistake on my part but I just can't seem to figure it out and don't want to waste anymore time than I already have on it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {


    public static Character req = '/'; 

    public static boolean datecheck(String d){
        String hold = d; 
        String[] a = new String[1];
        Character one = hold.charAt(2);
        Character two = hold.charAt(5); 

        //check to make sure the "/" are where they need to be
        if(one.equals(req)&&two.equals(req)){
        return true; 
        }
        else
            return false; 
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("welcome to the BrightSide Scheduler "
            + "\nplease input the day you wish to schedule:");
    String date = input.next();
    input.close();
    try{
    datecheck(date);
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("didnt work");
    }

    if (datecheck(date)==true){
        System.out.print("Success");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: When I run this code there is no infinite loop

Comment: To clarify, after you type something in and hit enter/return to add a new line, instead of printing "didn't work", "Success", or "fail", the scanner simply waits for more input?

Comment: There's no need to close the `Scanner`. You can remove `input.close();`.

Comment: `input.next()` is waiting for one token, i.e. it's waiting on something that is not a space or newline. Simply pressing enter will not do it. If that's what you want, change code to `input.nextLine()`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure why its wasn't working before but its working now and I I did was re open eclipse. Whatever I guess, thanks for the help all

Comment: The code is working in my end. I didn't find any issue. But I'd suggest you to use the primitive type `char` instead of the object type `Character` for your static variables. Additionally, it's not a good idea to use keywords such as `date` to name your variable, rather, use a customized name like `myDate` or a more meaningful name such as `scheduleDate` for your String type date variable. And as @Andreas suggested, use `nextLine()` rather than `next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had edited out some comments I had in my code with the original problem before asking this question to save some of the eyesore. It is in the code block below. An import of the LinkedList and a large block of comments that I decided not to use just yet until I reached that part of my program. And apparently removing all of that extra allowed my program to work but I'm not entirely sure why...

so below is the problem recreated, I had fixed my own problem just by editing our the comments and import I suppose.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {



/*public class Date {
private String day;
private String month;
private String year; 


public Date(String day, String month, String year){
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;

}
public String getDay() {
    return day;
}
public String getMonth(){
    return month;
}
public String getYear(){
    return year; 
}

//String[] options = new String[15]; 
}*/

public static Character req = '/'; 

public static boolean datecheck(String d){
    String hold = d; 
    String[] a = new String[1];
    Character one = hold.charAt(2);
    Character two = hold.charAt(5);
    //take user input an search through the string at to make sure it is 
    //formated correctly, then return true to continue the scheduler
    for(int x = -1; x<5; x = x+ 3){
        while(x != -1){
            int n = 0; 
            a[n] = hold.substring(x,x+1);
            n++;
        }

    }
    //check to make sure the "/" are where they need to be
    if(one.equals(req)&&two.equals(req)){
    return true; 
    }
    else
        return false; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("welcome to the BrightSide Scheduler "
            + "\nplease input the day you wish to schedule:");
    String date = input.next();
    input.close();
    try{
    datecheck(date);
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("didnt work");
    }

    if (datecheck(date)==true){
        System.out.print("Success");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
}

}
```

here is what my console looked like:
[console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIRM4.png)